# How do I root Cruz Tablet?

Tags: google-play-store, rooting

I am relatively new to the Android scene, and have recently bought my first official android-powered device. The cruz tablet was just $199 at Best Buy so I figured I culd give it a try. Unfortunately, it's very limited. I can live with the hardware shortcomings (no camera, no Bluetooth), but I want access to the full Android Market.

I believe a rooting is in order. Can someone please point me in the direction of rooting instructions for this device? Is rooting the same for each Android device? I haven't found much info on the net about this particular tablet. Anything I can learn from here would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!
Thomas

Comment: There are currently no methods to root this tablet. However, you do have root access when using adb.

Answer (score 2):

I have a rooted Velocity Micro Cruz T301 (now running on Android 2.2 Froyo).
You can find [instructions](http://www.slatedroid.com/topic/14203-i-rooted-my-cruz-tablet/) for any Cruz tablet on [Slatedroid forums](http://www.slatedroid.com/forum/135-velocity-cruz-tablet/).

So far this forum is the best source of info on this tablets.